# Как узнать размер кэша браузера через javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется ссылка, при нажатии, у пользователя грузиться файл с сервера, можно ли как то узнать размер кэша у браузера через javascript/jquery, после того когда узнаем размер кэша сравниваем его с размером файла и если файл не превышает объема кэша разрешаем загрузку файла

Answer (score 0):

Боюсь, размер `cache` браузера вы не сможете получить, нет `API`, которое предоставляет такие данные.

Тут либо сервер должен решать, нужно ли отдать новый файл или нет. Через заголовки можно управлять этим моментом

Либо разруливать это на клиенте, опять же: сервер возвращает нам заголовки, по которым мы можем определить, нужно ли загрузить файл или же нет. Хранить можно в `localStorage`. Как вариант, хранить дату последнего изменения файла и если в заголовках/`API` приходит новое значение, то загружаем файл.

[Вот тут можно почитать](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8/Cache-Control)

Answer (score 0):

Сидел на досуге и сделал вот такие методы (Работает вроде правильно, но за эффективность не ручаюсь), если есть предложения по улучшению кода, напишите в комментариях, спасибо!

```js
/**
 * возвращает приблизительный размер всех кэшей (в байтах)
 * @returns {Promise}
 */
function cachesSize() {
  return caches.keys().then(a => {
    return Promise.all(
      a.map(n => caches.open(n).then(c => cacheSize(c)))
    ).then(a => a.reduce((acc, n) => acc + n, 0));
  });
}
```

```js
/**
 * возвращает приблизительный размер одного кэша (в байтах)
 * @param {Promise} c Cache
 * @example cacheSize(await caches.open('CacheName'))
 * @returns {Promise}
 */
function cacheSize(c) {
  return c.keys().then(a => {
    return Promise.all(
      a.map(req => c.match(req).then(res => res.clone().blob().then(b => b.size)))
    ).then(a => a.reduce((acc, n) => acc + n, 0));
  });
}
```